# Ruby case and === on type comparison

Tags: ruby

I know that case statements use `===`, so:

```
a = "foo"
=>"foo"

case a
when String
  puts "hi"
end
=> hi
```

but strangely:

```
a === String
 => false
```

I was expecting the last expression to return true, what am I missing?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class has to be on the left hand side:

```
String === a
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

To check that class of the variable is `String` use the equality operator `==`.

```
> a.class == String
=> true
```

`Case` statement uses the `===` operator which is not equality. It's implementation is different for different types(read the documentation 
for more information). Its implementation `is_a?` for the specific case below:

```
> String === 'foo'
=> true

> String === String
=> false
```

Comment: The example isn't really self-explanatory, would you explain what's going on?

Comment: your original answer was unrelated to the question, I specifically asked about this expression: a === String and not a way of comparing types. glad you updated appending my answer.

Comment: I agree, my original answer was incomplete. I wanted to point out that your use of the `===` operator was incorrect and I was trying to answer quickly. I did not append your answer to my answer. If you look at the time of your answer and edit to my answer, they are exactly 5 minutes ago. Anyways, I was just trying to help